# Navigation features missing in Kentico 13

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-13

In Kentico 12, **Content** module had navigation feature which came with very useful menu action functionality. It seems to be completely missing in Kentico 13. Does it need to be configured or how do we go about implementing the similar functionality.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a response from Kentico support and they confirm it has been removed. Posting the response here, just in case it helps anyone else.

> Thanks for writing in to us today!
> This was completely removed as it does not make much sense in MVC development model. The difference is that in portal engine, the site, the pages were served by Kentico application. But in Kentico 13, the site is served by your front end app - so you can implement whatever navigation logic you want. You can simply add custom fields to the page type where the editors will select desired action/value and then, when you retrieve the page's data in your front end app, you will check the value and perform desired action. This is now fully in your hands.

Comment: If you don't want to 'reinvent' the wheel, the Baseline project for KX13 has a Navigation module that has much of this built in.  It comes with a Generic.Navigation page type that you can either manually or automatically generate navigation, various repositories to aid, and with some additional modules you can also get the "Navigate to nearest child" type of behavior the previous Navigation system had.

I talked on it at the Kentico Conference as well (the baseline project). https://github.com/KenticoDevTrev/XperienceCommunity.Baseline